# Error handling in Promise / bluebird.js

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

Whats the difference between those `then` calls in context of handling errors ?

```
.then(functionThatReturnsPromise(arg))

.then(function() {
    return functionThatReturnsPromise(arg);
})
```

In first example, if function `functionThatReturnsPromise` throws `error`, catch block isnt called and bluebird prints error;

```
Possibly unhandled Error: <msg>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first one runs `functionThatReturnPromise` before the previous promise completes! If you write

```
blah()
.then( functionThatReturnsPromise(arg) )
```

its like writing

```
var firstPromise = blah();
var x = functionThatReturnsPromise(arg)
firstPromise.then(x);
```

Additionally, `then`  expects to be passed a callback function but you are passing it a promise object. Its no surprise that its not working correctly.

Comment: Oh, ty, promise spesifications are really messed with my brain.